# How to integrate Postgres DB and services like FCM or One Signal for push notification?

Tags: postgresql, flutter, push-notification

I wish to implement push notifications in my flutter app. Initially, I wanted to build something in-house to implement the notification until I realized the limitations that would eventually emerge later on. So I wish to use FCM or One Signal notification services for that matter.
I have a Postgres database and flutter app running on AVD. I am using API in PHP to display the data on the app.

Now how I wish the push notification to work; say I have a table 'A' in my DB, and whenever a new collection of rows is inserted into the table I wish to have the push notification sent to the app. I understood that services like FCM and One Signal send out the push notification to the app but my query is how do I configure my Postgres database to FCM or One Signal so that push notification is sent with the update made to the table in DB.

Please correct me if my question is misplaced.

Could anyone help me with relevant content or links? Thanks.